# Androidx problem with 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, androidx, material-components-android, android-design-library

How can I make  the last line to work  with androidx`    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the support libraries:

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`
```

and use:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```